Terracing in Blender and Float32 > UInt16 Tiff (Daniel Huffman tutorial)
I have read every question here about this particular problem and everywhere else but have not yet found a working solution. As you can see there is some significant terracing visible.
I am working with Copernicus DEM GLO-30 32 Bit, floating (DGED & INSPIRE format).
Here are the steps that I am following (software is QGIS):

Clip the target DEM.
Normalise the data to range from 0 to 65535 (while the file still is float32)
Reproject to desired CRS (using Cubic 4x4) and set output data type to UInt16 (in the same warp / reproject dialog)
Export geoTIFF as rendered image (not raw data)
Import the TIFF in Blender as a displacement map.

Checking the properties of the final DEM layer in QGIS confirms that the file is indeed in UInt16 format and its ranges are 0 to 65535.
What am I missing?



Is this the tutorial? How do you normalize the data to 0-65535?

Yes, that's the tutorial. A nice person in Reddit pointed out the problem > raw data was supposed to be exported, and not rendered image.
As to your question, you normalise it using Raster > Raster Calculator and the formula ("name" - min value) / (max value - min value) * 65535. Where "name" is the name of your layer (but selected from the list on the calculator window with @1 or something after it). The min and max values you get from double click on layer > properties > somewhere there. It is important to normalise it before converting to Uint16.

I just tried with GLO-30 float32 in GTIIFF format from OpenTopography over an area in the Himalayas (40m - >8000m) and couldn't reproduce any contouring. Didn't make any difference with my test, but make sure recalculate the actual max and min of your data, don't rely on default estimated stats.

Suggest you add the "raw data was supposed to be exported, and not rendered image" and save someone else the time spent trying to figure the problem.

Yes, I’ll do that. I am new to stack exchange so thanks for the tip. On the min and max values, I always get them from the properties of the exact dem layer.

When exporting the TIFF > raw data is supposed to be exported, and not rendered image.
